# Redirecting state: null is not an object (evaluating 'name')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When a user enters the state `cloud`, it checks if a current variable is found, and if it isn't, it redirects them to a different state. But for some reason, I get the following error on the redirect.

If I just go directly to **/new**, it does not give me the error. Only when the redirect occurs.

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/cloud');

    var billable = ['$rootScope', '$state', function ($rootScope, $state) { 
        if(!$rootScope.billable) $state.go('new'); 
    }];

    $stateProvider

    .state('new', {
        url: '/new',
        views: { 'main': { templateUrl: 'pages/templates/new.html', controller: 'new' } },
    })

    .state('cloud', {
        url: '/cloud',
        views: { 'main': { templateUrl: 'pages/templates/cloud.html', controller: 'cloud' } },
        onEnter: billable
    })

})
```

> Error: null is not an object (evaluating 'name')
>   updateView@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:3953:87
>   http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:3924:21
>   $broadcast@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:14720:33
>   load@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:3678:32
>   http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:3554:30
>   proceed@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:474:48
>   invoke@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:470:33
>   http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:449:20
>   http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:3557:46
>   forEach@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:331:24
>   resolveViews@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:3551:16
>   processQueue@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:13189:29
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:13205:39
>   $digest@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:14217:36
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:14440:33
>   completeOutstandingRequest@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:4905:15
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:5285:33

Comment: have you tried moving `billable` into `.run()` instead of defining it in `config`?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have this configured, I don't believe any `states` have been defined yet because the application has not yet been bootstrapped.  Additionally, route redirects like this are typically placed in the `run` method, not in the `config`.

You could pass billable (as a boolean or whatever you need it to be) in the params of the url and redirect based on that.

i.e.

```
// I'm assuming you're using UI-Router  
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/cloud');
    $stateProvider
    .state('new', {
        url: '/new',
        views: { 'main': { templateUrl: 'pages/templates/new.html', controller: 'new' } },
    })
    .state('cloud', {
        url: '/cloud?billable',
        views: { 'main': { templateUrl: 'pages/templates/cloud.html', controller: 'cloud' } },
    })   
}])
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (!toParams.billable) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $state.go('new');
    }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I try and use a service to grab my billable param and it doesnt seem to work in the run though. I'm a bit confused why